# Decrypt using an RSA public key in Python3

Tags: python, encryption

In order to use a third-party web-service API there is a challenge/response aspect to the login. This requires sending a random challenge to the service, encrypted with their (RSA) public key and receiving a challenge from the site encrypted with my public key. In turn both parties must decrypt the challenge presented to them and return it to the other side (so the server then demonstrates it possesses its private key and I likewise).

The creation of the challenge is something akin to the following:

```
encrypted_server_challenge = self._private_key.private_encrypt(
    server_challenge, RSA.pkcs1_padding)
```

and determining if it's authentic is like so:

```
decrypted_challenge = self._server_pub_key.public_decrypt(
    block, RSA.pkcs1_padding)
```

I know this isn't good practice but I do not have the option of changing this (the third-party service dictates this procedure).

At present (using Python 2.7) I'm using M2Crypto which supports private-encrypt/public-decrypt.

I guess I have two questions:

1. Is there a library available under Python3 that would allow this
   pattern to be used (PyCrypto for example specifically forbids it and
   M2Crypto doesn't currently work with Python3 that I'm aware)?
2. Is there a way to rewrite this such that I could use the existing
   crypto signature methods to do this and have the same result?